# Error with line numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, line-numbering

I am using IEEE journal template and after enabling the line number the text is showing error like the figure.

I used this command to add line numbers

```
\usepackage[switch,pagewise]{lineno}
%\setlength\columnsep{15pt}
\linenumbers

\definecolor{brightmaroon}{rgb}{0.76, 0.13, 0.28}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\rmfamily \footnotesize \color{brightmaroon}}
```

I was wondering if somebody could help me with it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please edit your question to show a small, complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: Which of the IEEE journal templates are you using?

Comment: I hope you don't intend to keep those numbers in the final version.